# React-Axios Getting error 401 (Unauthorized) for PUT Method

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, authorization, put

I have gone through many posts and tested most of them but I still get this error.
It's interesting that I don't get this error for the get method. I get this error only for put method.
thanks to everyone

[axios error 401 (Unauthorized)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaqO5.jpg)

```
axios
      .put("/api/v1/Profile", {
        fullName: userName,
        gender: Number(userGender),
        phoneNumber: userNumber,
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
          Authorization: `Token ${userToken}`,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

There is no error for the get method, but it gives an error for the put method
I tested it with Postman and it works without errors

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your `Authorization` header. You're using the right syntax ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization)):

```
Authorization: <auth-scheme> <authorization-parameters>
```

Given `userToken` is your `<authorization-parameters>`. The problem comes from the `<auth-scheme>` for which you used `Token`: this is not a valid scheme according to the [list maintained by IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml).

Hard to be sure without much information, but I guess what you want is:

```
Authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}`,
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help
But I also tested this and I get the error again.
I do not receive errors with Postman
Please tell me any information that may help to solve this problem
Thank you my friend

Comment: My backend uses c#
Does this have any effect on this error?

Comment: do you have any error message about a cors issue?

Comment: mode: 'no-cors' 
After you said I checked and set it to no-cors
Is that what you think I did?

Comment: depending on your server CORS configuration, you may need to let the cors mode enabled: that's a mechanism which is enabled in browsers, but not in "outside the browser" requests like in postman. I am not familiar with c# and .net: I suggest you to check your server configuration, and maybe post a c# specific question :)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved with this format:

```
axios({
  method: 'put',
  url: 'api/v1/Profile/',
  data: {
    fullName: userName,
    gender: Number(userGender),
    phoneNumber: '',
  },
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}`,
  },
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```